# custom tableViewCell labels not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a custom view cell on UITableViewController.

```
@interface PPCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tableViewTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tableViewSubtitle;
@end

PPCustomCell *cell = (PPCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell.accessoryView == nil) {
        UIImage *buttonUpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button4.png"];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitle:@"Unpaid" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button sizeToFit];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(tappedButton:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryView = button;
    }
    cell.accessoryView.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.tableViewTitle.text = [[remindersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]reminderName];
    cell.tableViewSubtitle.text =[[remindersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]reminderDueDate];
```

but getting this error
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell tableViewTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Please help.

UPDATE - I was using this, removed this line it worked.
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Does your `PPCustomCell` class have a property named `tableViewTitle`? The error says that it doesn't.

Comment: Did you remember to change the class of the cell (in the storyboard or xib) to your custom class. The error message is saying that you're trying to access a property on a UITableViewCell, not your PPCustomCell.

Comment: Maybe you forgot about setting something when switching from view controller to table view controller? Your app obviously allocates UITableViewCell objects instead of PPCustomCell objects.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether this is in a UIViewController or a UITableViewController. You should check the class of cell with a log -- it certainly seems like you're returning a UITableViewCell instead of the one you want.

Comment: Can you show your custom class header file??

Comment: If you made your cell in a storyboard, then you shouldn't register the class (if you register the class, the system expects to find the definition of the view in your class code). Did you log the cell class in cellForRowAtIndexPath to see what it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocating any cells!

Before your `if (cell.accessoryView == nil)` call, you should include the following:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[PPCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:etc...];
}
```

Comment: If the cell was made in a storyboard, it won't ever be nil, so there's no need for this check.